# No module named '_tf' error when doing "writing a tf broadcaster (py) tutorial

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all  Below is the error I'm getting when I try to launch the launch file using the command
**roslaunch learning_tf start_demo.launch**

```
File "/home/cj/catkin_ws/src/learning_tf/nodes/turtle_tf_broadcaster.py", line 6, in  
import tf
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tf/__init__.py", line 28, in 

    from _tf import *
ImportError: No module named '_tf'
```

I tried updating using pacman -Syu and tried reinstalling the "tf" package but the result is the same.

I'm still a beginner and appreciate if someone can help me to correct this error.

PS.
I followed the steps given in this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29)

This error occurs when I try to do the `roslaunch learning_tf start_demo.launch` step.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249720/no-module-named-%27_tf%27-error-when-doing-%22writing-a-tf-broadcaster-(py)-tutorial/) by [Chamikajp](https://answers.ros.org/users/23283/chamikajp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is the leading underscore before `tf` in the import. Remove this and you should be good to go.
But updating/reinstalling `tf` will not change this. The problem is in the `learning_tf` repo.

Where did you get this demo from? Did you clone from github or did you copy'n'paste stuff or did you change anything?

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-09**:
If it is [this](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20(Python)) demo, then I think it's a simple copy-paste error, as there is no underscore before `tf` in the example.

**Comment by [Chamikajp](https://answers.ros.org/users/23283/chamikajp/) on 2016-12-09**:
Thank you very much for your replays..
[This is the tutorial part](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29) I was following .
The file in the  `learning_tf` repo contains the  `import tf` problem is with the **init**.py file..

**Comment by [Chamikajp](https://answers.ros.org/users/23283/chamikajp/) on 2016-12-09**:
It contains the   `from _tf import *`  .. I'll try editing the **init**.py file and get back to you..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-09**:
But which "repo" are you talking about specifically?

**Comment by [Chamikajp](https://answers.ros.org/users/23283/chamikajp/) on 2016-12-09**:
Sorry if my comment is confusing. I meant the learning_tf folder which has the file containing the import tf code.. I exactly followed the steps given in the tutorial. Error is generated by this file /opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tf/**init**.py"